# How do I add components dynamically in React?

Tags: html, reactjs

[image]

In the attached picture, I want a different component to be added below the 'Choose Round Type' option based on the round type selected.

[image]

Adding to a single round is no issue. But when I add a new round and try to do the same for it, the components are essentially the same thing but repeated.

[image]

As you can see here, both of the forms are either visible or not.

I am following a wrong approach wherein I just add the form component to the mapped round and because the form is same for every round, it connects to all of the forms of the other rounds.

What I want is that I should be able to select different round types and get the corresponding input fields in every round.[image]

As visible, once I click on a different round type in the second round, the first one also changes.

The Add a Round functionality is made using AntDesign Components.

What I tried to do:

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { useStore } from "react-redux";
    import { Input, Radio, Form, Button, Space } from 'antd';
    import { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } from '@ant- 
    design/icons';
    import "./createQuizPage.css";

    const RoundTypeScheme = ({ type, count }) =>
    {
        console.log(type, count);
        try
        {
            switch(type)
            {
                case "Pounce":
                    return (
                    <div id = {count}>
                        <label>Marks for correct answer (Direct) 
    </label>
                        <Input size = "small" />
                        <label>Marks for incorrect answer (Direct) 
    </label>
                        <Input size = "small" />
                        <label>Marks for correct answer (Pounce) 
    </label>
                        <Input size = "small" />
                        <label>Marks for incorrect answer (Pounce) 
    </label>
                        <Input size = "small" />
                        <hr />
                    </div>
                );
            case "Pounce + Bounce":
            case "Differential":
            case "Buzzer":
            case "Long Visual Connect":
            default:
                return (<></>)
        }
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

    const CreateQuizPage = () =>
    {
        const [type, setType] = useState("");
        const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
        const store = useStore();
        let quiz_name = store.getState().quiz;
        const quiz_rounds = ["Preliminary", "Main"]
        const quiz_sub_rounds = ["Pounce", "Pounce + Bounce", "Buzzer", "Differential", "Long Visual Connect"]

    const roundScores = (e) =>
    {
        setType(e.target.value);
    }

    const addRound = () =>
    {
        setCount(prev => (prev + 1));
    }

    return (
        <div id = "createQuizPage">
            <Form
                name="basic"
                className = "createQuizPage__form"
            >
                <h1>Name: {quiz_name}</h1>
                <Form.Item>
                    <label>Choose Quiz Type </label>
                    <Radio.Group
                        options = {quiz_rounds}
                        optionType = "button"
                        buttonStyle = "solid"
                        className = "createQuizPage__type-button"
                    ></Radio.Group>
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.List name="users">
                    {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
                    <>
                        {fields.map(({ key, name, fieldKey, ...restField }) => (
                        <Space key={key} align="baseline" className = "createQuizPage__quiz-round">
                            <Form.Item
                                {...restField}
                                name={[name, 'round_type']}
                                fieldKey={[fieldKey, 'round_type']}
                                rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing Quiz Round' }]}
                            >
                                <label>Choose Round Type </label>
                                <Radio.Group
                                    options = {quiz_sub_rounds}
                                    optionType = "button"
                                    buttonStyle = "solid"
                                    onChange = {(e) => roundScores(e)}
                                ></Radio.Group>
                                <RoundTypeScheme type = {type} count = {count}/>
                            </Form.Item>
                            <MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => remove(name)} />
                        </Space>
                        ))}
                        <Form.Item>
                            <Button onClick={() => {add(); addRound();}} icon={<PlusOutlined />}>
                                Add a Round
                            </Button>
                        </Form.Item>
                    </>
                    )}
                </Form.List>
            </Form> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default CreateQuizPage;
```

Comment: Please add some code samples of what you did so far or have a codesandbox. It'll help people help you.

Comment: I have added the code. Basically, I want the inputs to be visible on selection of a particular round and every round would have different inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you facing is caused because you pass the type and view dependencies as props to the actual component and they're still reactive.

You need to either:

1. Save the initial config of the round component and then if the props will change, it won't change the UI of the round.
2. Hold in the container component an array of the round configs and then loop over them and pass each round config to the round component.

I think #2 would be better in terms of architecture and code readability